# Do we really need to avoid constructors with default values for Fragments and Activites in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, delegates

I am great fan of Kotlin and how it allows us to write better code. One of the best features is interface implementation delegation which looks like this:

```
class A(val someObject:SomeInterface) : SomeInterface by someObject
```

`someObject` has to be singleton (object), has to be created using constructor after keyword `by` (but then you cannot reference to it, or maybe someone has idea how to do it?) or has to be provided in constructor.

In Android messy and bad world we are discouraged to use constructors in fragments and activites due to configuration changes. But how about this:

```
class MyFragment(val someObject:SomeInterface = SomeObjectImpl()):Fragment,SomeInterface by someObject
```

I tried to change configuration and event I allowed system to kill my appliction and still, everything is looking ok, my object is creating again and again with my fragment. Is this valid, or am I missing something?
Happy Kotlin everyone!

Comment: `due to configuration changes` and due to process death.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39785939/2413303

Comment: Yes I tested that as well, still working on pixel, but I am not sure if there are some edge cases that can create other results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid. The reason you're discouraged from overloading fragment constructors is that Android can recreate them, and it will use the default one: `MyFragment()`

But the way Kotlin implements default parameter values behind the scenes is by creating additional constructors. You can decompile your class and see it contains two constructors now, one receiving `someObject`, and another empty.

From the JVM perspective the empty constructor would look like this:

```
public A() {
  this(new SomeObjectImpl());
}
```

Calling it will populate your fragment with new instances of implemented classes.

Comment: So what happens when the android framework recreates your fragment and uses the default (no-arg) constructor?

Comment: Yea what will happen then? I tried to test it and my values weren't null but I just wanted to make sure. Framework uses reflection to create fragment? If it will call empty constructor then my someObject value would be null

Comment: I expanded my answer a bit. If you supplied default arguments, your object value would not be null.